# second element(contenttab) is too height/Exceeded of container(outer) after add padding to header tag

Tags: html, css

My html is :

```
<div id="outer">
    <header><h1>The Header</h1></header>
    <div id="contenttab">
        <table>
            blablabla
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS :

```
#outer{
height:70%;
width:900px;
left:50%;
margin:0 auto;
position:absolute;
top:20px;
z-index:1001;
transform:translate(-50%, 0);
-webkit-transform:translate(-50%, 0);
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
            box-sizing:border-box;
}
header{
    background-color:#f6f7f9;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:15px !important;
    font-weight:bold !important;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}
#contenttab{
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

why my contenttab exceeded the height of #outer div ? how to fix that? I have try adding border-box css to parent div but not solve my problem . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried out your posted html/css and your #contenttab div is exceeding the height of it's container because of your css rule of `height: 100%` on the #contenttab;

It's a lot easier to see/debug the issue using borders on your elements, add the following:

```
#outer {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#contenttab {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ffa500;
}
```

You are telling the #contenttab to have 100% full height of it's container, however then you are also adding additional content(the header element) which causes the internal elements to have more than 100% height than it's container can hold.

Either change the height rule on the #contenttab to auto or less than 100%. Or add css rule overflow: hidden(or auto) to your #outer css rule.